# += operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

This is a code representing a fraction with an operator overloading

```
class Fraction
{
private:
int _counter, _denominator;
public:
Fraction(int _x, int _y);

Fraction & operator+=(int b)
{
    _counter = _counter + b*_denominator;
    return  *this;
}

Fraction & operator-=(int b)
{
    _counter = _counter - b*_denominator;
    return  *this;
}
};

Fraction::Fraction(int _x, int _y)
{
    _counter = _x;
    _denominator = _y;
}


void main()
{
    Fraction *f = new Fraction(2, 4);

    f += 5;
}
```

Can someone tell me why the operator `+=` overloading doesn't work?

Comment: You need to use `*f += 5;` or `f->operator+=(5);`

Comment: `f` is a pointer for absolutely no reason. That is the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `new`? Use variables with automatic storage (i.e. the stack) whenever possible.

Comment: Or even better, don't use `new`: `Fraction f(2, 4); f += 5;`

Comment: When you're done with your pointer, don't forget to delete it: `delete f;`. Also, you probably [shouldn't start names with underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: `main()` returns `int`. Always.

Comment: BTW, your implementation is wrong when denominator is negative.

Comment: @Jarod42: I dno, is it? This is not a conventional operator overloading, so it seems to me that the semantics are pretty much up to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You are overloading the operator for *Fraction* objects, but adding 5 to a *Fraction* * object - a pointer to Fraction.

Something like this would work:

```
(*f) += 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement `operator+=()` you should be aware of it and use it by yourself, so this code:

```
_counter = _counter + b*_denominator;
```

Is better written as:

```
_counter += b * _denominator;
```

As it is shorter and less verbose.

About the error: Use object instead of pointer, as this is not java:

```
int main() // main() must return int
{
   Fraction f(2, 4);
   f += 5;
}
```

Comment: _"should be written as"_ Why?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is shorter and less verbose

Comment: @Slava: so *may* instead of *should*.

Comment: Plus it makes sense to use `+=` on data members in the definition of `+=` for the class.

Comment: But why are you leading with a largely irrelevant and misleading statement? Answer the question first, no?

Comment: @Jarod42 hmm english not my first language probably I do not understand the difference.

Comment: @Slava: *should* is nearer than *must/have to*. *may* is for a possibility. (English is not my mother language neither)